# Install application only on notification tab

Tags: android, android-notifications, notificationmanager

I show a notification to the user once an application has been downloaded.

I also have a installApk method which installs the downloaded application but in the code piece (completeNotification) the application gets **automatically** installed. I need it to only install once the user **tabs the notification**.

Did I overlooked something?

Thank you for your help.

*The completeNotification method:*

```
public void completeNotification() {
        Intent install = installApk(urlPath, context, mNotificationManager,
                NOTIFYCATIONID);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, install, 0);

        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(appName)
                .setContentText("ready to install.");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pending);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.placeholder);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

*The installApk method:*

```
public static Intent installApk(String urlPath, Context context,
                                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager, int NOTIFYCATIONID) {
        Intent apkIntent = new Intent();
        apkIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        apkIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        File apkFile = new File(urlPath);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(apkFile);
        apkIntent
                .setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        context.startActivity(apkIntent);
        mNotificationManager.cancel(NOTIFYCATIONID);
        return apkIntent;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this line:

```
context.startActivity(apkIntent);
```

Comment: I already wanted but I only can within 10 minutes. I`ll mark it.